# Unable to Debug a Website in Visual Studios

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, web

Here is my situation...
I have to maintain a website with multiple applications. We no longer have any of the solution files and the code is deployment code (so it uses DLL's instead of the original classes).

I basically grab the code from the website and stick it in a Visual Studio projects folder (This is generally C# code with Javascript that was originally developed on VS). I then open Visual Studios's 2010 Professional (VS) and open website, using the path in the project folder. I then add references to all the DLL files and if all the includes, images , and css files paths are referenced correctly, I can hit F5 and get the webpage to appear with some functionality. This creates a Project file in the Projects folder which I can then open instead of opening a website.

The problem is that I am unable to debug. If I set a breakpoint, it goes from solid red to outline red upon start of debugging. The standard message is "The breakpoint will not be currently hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document".

I have cleared out the symbols and reloaded.
I have debug = true in all my Web.config files. 
I have gone into project properties and set the startup project action to "Start".

Any ideas why I can't debug ? My other projects that I develop from scratch work fine, but it is these projects that I am trying to get working from website files that won't debug.

My goal is to get every one of the Website apps under VS control were I can fix bugs and make improvements. Not very easy when the original source code is no longer available.
Please Help !

Thank You,

Eric

Comment: Are you using the VS built-in web server or IIS?

Comment: Slightly confused... In part of your question you state that you grab C# code from the website, but elsewhere you say that the original source code is no longer available. Which of these is true?

Comment: As Richard says, if you really don't have the C# code i.e. the codebehind files, then you can't debug it. You might be able to decompile the dll files and get the source code that way. [http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77/is-there-any-way-to-decompile-a-net-assembly-or-program](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77/is-there-any-way-to-decompile-a-net-assembly-or-program)

Comment: It's unclear: he may just mean that the source code is not in the website itself. If he has the code _somewhere_ and he has the PDB files alongside the DLLs, he should still be able to debug. He says he's setting breakpoints somewhere--what does that mean unless he's looking at code?

Comment: I am using VS built in web server.

Comment: As for the code, It is the deployment code, so your mostly going to see .asp pages ( I guess the code behind files get compiled into the DLL files, is that correct ?)

Comment: I did notice that there are some PDB files in the BIN folder, but not every DLL file inthe BIN folder has a PDB file.

Comment: O.K, just took another look. It looks like a mixed bag of code. There are some Code Behind files, but there are also DLL file. I suspect that they deployed from the project folder (not the Build Folder), which would include the code behinds, but also the DLL files in the BIN folder. If this is true, the program would still use the DLL files, regardless if the code behind files are present or not.

Comment: So the big questionis, how do I make this work with debugging ? I can create solutions for each DLL (using JetBrainsdotpeek) and copy the individual .cs files, but where do they go in the project and will they be referenced properly. Most importantly, wil this give methe ability to debug ?  Thanks,  Eric

Answer (score 0):

I fought this issue for a half of a day.   I'm currently maintaining a website application.  What worked for me is going into the project's Property Pages >> Start Options and changing the server to "Use Custom Server".  I believe this setting will use IIS and not IIS Express.  I started the project and was immediately able to debug.

[image]